# UnsupportedOperationException: Invalid content type application/json

Tags: rest-assured

I am automating the rest api's through rest-assured.

When i test the same api through REST Client i didn't get any issue, but when i am automating through `Rest Assured` i am getting the invalid content-type error.

my rest api is as below:

```
 Response res = given()
                .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                .body(model)
                .with()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .then()
                .post(ConfigReader.get("asset.temperature.push.url"));

        return res.body().asString();
```

Error is:

```
{"message":"Execution exception[[UnsupportedOperationException: Invalid content type. Content-Type should be application/json or text/json, receivedapplication/json; charset=UTF-8]]"}
```

How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue, because of internal application, it is directly verifying for the content-type as `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` that caused the problem.

By default rest-assured will send the default charset `UTF-8`, but as the application verifying for `utf-8` it caused the problem.

Raised issue against application anyway to solve this.